# Python:Taking the first character without Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

My code is about creating a password using the first character/digit of every word/number as a character in a sentence/phrase and printing it just as so.

> Example: Stop and smell the 350 "roses". -> Sast3r. (Ignoring
>   quotations using r instead)

This would be very easy using lists, but you cannot use them in this assignment for my code. So, I don't know what to do now after what I have done so far

Function:

```
def create_password(phrase):
q = "'"  # quotations
dq = '"'  # double quotes

password = phrase[0]

for i in phrase:
    x = phrase.find(" ")
    if i.isalnum:
        password += phrase[x + 1]
    elif x == q or x == dq:
        password += phrase[x + 2]

return password
```

Main:

```
# Imports
from credentials import create_password

# Inputs
phrase = str(input("Enter a sentence or phrase: "))

# Outputs
password = create_password(phrase)
print(password)
```

Comment: Strings are pretty much the same thing as a list of characters. Almost everything you can do with a list, can be done with a string.

Comment: I think you're on the right track so far. When I first read your question, I immediately thought of `.find`, which seems to be what you are after. However, `.find()` has a second argument, which tells you after what point to start looking.

Comment: You could always use iterator: `l='abc'` and then `next(iter(l))` will give you `a`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is more straightforward to walk through the entire phrase without worrying about splitting on spaces. Instead keep track of whether or not you've just seen a space. You only want to add the character after just seeing a space.

```
def create_password(phrase):
    q = "'"  # quotations
    dq = '"'  # double quotes

    #Initialize the password to be an empty string
    password = ""

    #We are at the start of a new word (want to add first index to password)
    new_word = True

    #Walk through every character in the phrase
    for char in phrase:

        #We only want to add char to password if the following is all true:
        #(1) It's a letter or number
        #(2) It's at the start of a new word
        #(3) It's not a single quote
        #(4) It's not a double quote
        if char.isalnum and new_word:
            if char != q and char != dq:
                password += char
                new_word = False #<-- After adding char, we are not at a new word

        #If we see a space then we are going to be at a new word
        elif char == " ":
            new_word = True

    return password

p = create_password('Stop and smell the 350 "roses"')
print(p)
```

Output:

```
Sast3r
```

Comment: I see where you're coming from leaving the .find function. You're way makes great use of the boolean ignoring messing with the strings. Great Job :D

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely on the right track! Using the [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) method is definitely the way to go!

However, you need to understand what the `str.find()` method does. Look at the signature:

```
str.find(sub [,start [,end) -> int

    # sub -> character to find
    # start -> where the function should start looking in the string
    # end -> where the function should stop looking

    # Returns a number, which is the place it found the character. 
    # If it didn't find anything, then return -1.
```

Without telling the function where to start, it will always find the first occurrence of the character in the string. It won't know that you're going through each character of the string.

So let's change it up a little bit:

```
for char_index in xrange(len(phrase)):
    # Tell the method to look after char_index: we've already looked before this!
    x = phrase.find(' ', char_index) index

    if phrase[x+1].isalnum(): # It's a function, notice the brackets?
        password += phrase[x + 1]
    elif phrase[x+2] == q or phrase[x+2] == dq:
        password += phrase[x + 2]
```

Hopefully, this should get your desired password.

Comment: Ah, thanks for showing what .find actually does. I basically just plugged it in only knowing it counts the # of spaces. haha thanks

Answer (score 1):

Give priority to the use of built-in function, for example, every time you find the location of space, then why not directly in accordance with the space for spilt function, so that the string directly to the character list, each element is a word, and then remove each element in the list.

```
def create_password(phrase):
    password = ''
    phrase_list = phrase.split(' ')
    print (phrase_list)

    for i in phrase_list:
        print (i[0])
        password += i[0]
    return password

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Inputs
    phrase = str(input("Enter a sentence or phrase: "))

    # Outputs
    password = create_password(phrase)
    print(password)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try taking the first character in the string, and then every character that follows a space. It looks like you have the right idea.